# UIImageView not showing in app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` which is displayed using the following code:

```
profileImage = [self getImageFromUrl:@"http://i.imgur.com/l0HVdmR.png"];
if (profileImage == nil) {
    NSLog(@"SourceImage is nil");
} else {
    NSLog(@"SourceImage isn't nil");
}
profileImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
profileImageView.image = profileImage;
[profileImageView setFrame:CGRectMake((screenWidth/2)-(profileDiameter/2), profileDiameter/2, profileDiameter, profileDiameter)];
[profileImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
profileImageView.userInteractionEnabled = isEditing;

NSLog(@"Online image used");
if (profileImageView == nil) {
    NSLog(@"ImageView is nil");
} else {
    NSLog(@"ImageView isn't nil");
}
```

Later on I use the code `[mainScrollView addSubview:profileImageView` to add the `UIImageView` to the `UIScrollView` I have set up. The UIImageView used to correctly display this image without any trouble. However, the `UIImageView` has suddenly stopped displaying altogether, and I'm unsure of what change elsewhere in my code caused this.

The framing isn't to blame. The variables are the correct values and changing them didn't solve the issue. The `NSLog`s show both the `UIImage` and `UIImageView` to not be `nil`. If it helps, the `UITapGestureRecognizer` I have set up on the `UIImageView` does not register taps in the area in which the image should be - This may provide some clue regarding the symptoms of the bug.

All help appreciated.

Comment: You say it is displayed using that code but you do not add it as a subview of anything. Are you doing... `addSubView(profileImageView)` at any point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the value of `profileDiameter` was initialised or not. Also `addSubview` must be used.

Kindly upload some more details regarding how `profileDiameter` is found out.

Comment: Ironically, you unwittingly answered my question. It's quite niche, so unfortunately it like won't help many people in the future, but profileDiameter was initialized only after I used it in setting the frame of the UIImageView. I moved this code to be before I create the UIImageView, and the ImageView displays fine. Thanks.